# onActivityResult is not called in two tabhost in android

Tags: android

I am creating a mobile application in android, I am using 2 tabhost for my requirement. In first tab of second tabhost, i am taking mobile no. from mobile contact no., for that reason i am using that code...

```
contact.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    try{
                        Intent pickContactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
                        pickContactIntent.setType(Phone.CONTENT_TYPE); // Show user only contacts w/ phone numbers
                        System.out.println("pickContactIntent value in cont" + pickContactIntent);
                        System.out.println("PICK_CONTACT value in cont" + PICK_CONTACT);
                        startActivityForResult(pickContactIntent, PICK_CONTACT);



                    } catch(Exception e){
                        Toast.makeText(getParent(), "Number is not format", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            });
```

This code is successfully executed, its clear. Now I am using onActivityResult code.

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {
        case (PICK_CONTACT):
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri contactData = data.getData();

                 // Make sure the request was successful

                    // We only need the NUMBER column, because there will be only one row in the result
                    String[] projection = {Phone.NUMBER};


                    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contactData, projection, null, null, null);   
                    cursor.moveToFirst();

                    // Retrieve the phone number from the NUMBER column
                    int column = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);
                    String number = cursor.getString(column);

                    String newNum = number.replaceAll("-", "").trim();

                    newNum=newNum.replace("+91", "");

                    mob_no.setText(newNum);
                    }
        }
    }
```

It is not called, because i am checking all code in debugging. Why it is not called, I am searching solution from 2 days. I am so worried. Please solve my problem. Thanks.

whole code is ................................................................................
    public class Recharge_activity extends Activity{

```
    static int counter=0;
    ImageView contact;
    Spinner spinner;
    EditText mob_no;
    String mobile_no;
    TextView amt, user_name, user_crdt;
    Button btn_submit;
    ArrayList<String> adapter;
    AlertDialogManeger adm;
    String rech_operator="";
    private static final int PICK_CONTACT = 1;
    String UserBal;
    List<String> provider_name = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> provider_code = new ArrayList<String>();
    //String[] provider_name, provider_code;
    String urrl, cont_no, pvd_code, pvd_name, pvd_country, error="";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.globalrechargexml);

        //requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
        //setTitle(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.logo1));
        //getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.title_logo);

        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnr_oprt);
        spinner.setAdapter(null);
        adm = new AlertDialogManeger();
        amt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_amt);
        mob_no = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mobilenum);
        contact = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mobile_contact);
        //mob_no.requestFocus();

        btn_submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_rchg);
        user_name=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.u_name);
        /*user_name.setText(Global_variable.getUserID());*/
        user_crdt=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.t_crdt);
        /*user_crdt.setText(Global_variable.getUserCredit());*/
        mob_no.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);

        mob_no.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        user_name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        user_crdt.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));


        btn_submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                //Processdata();
            }
        });

        mob_no.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {

                mob_no.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                return false;
            }
        });

        amt.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {

                amt.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                //cont_no=mob_no.getText().toString();
                //setfillspinner();
                return false;
            }
        });

        amt.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                    KeyEvent event) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO) {
                    //Processdata();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        mob_no.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                    KeyEvent event) {

                mob_no.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                return false;
                }

        });


            contact.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    try{
                        Intent pickContactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
                        pickContactIntent.setType(Phone.CONTENT_TYPE); // Show user only contacts w/ phone numbers
                        System.out.println("pickContactIntent value in cont" + pickContactIntent);
                        System.out.println("PICK_CONTACT value in cont" + PICK_CONTACT);
                        startActivityForResult(pickContactIntent, PICK_CONTACT);



                    } catch(Exception e){
                        Toast.makeText(getParent(), "Number is not format", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            });

    }



    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        System.out.println("the value request code" + requestCode);
        System.out.println("the value resultCode" + resultCode);
        System.out.println("the value data" + data);
        switch (requestCode) {
        case (PICK_CONTACT):
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri contactData = data.getData();

                 // Make sure the request was successful

                    // We only need the NUMBER column, because there will be only one row in the result
                    String[] projection = {Phone.NUMBER};

                    // Perform the query on the contact to get the NUMBER column
                    // We don't need a selection or sort order (there's only one result for the given URI)
                    // CAUTION: The query() method should be called from a separate thread to avoid blocking
                    // your app's UI thread. (For simplicity of the sample, this code doesn't do that.)
                    // Consider using CursorLoader to perform the query.
                    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contactData, projection, null, null, null);   
                    cursor.moveToFirst();

                    // Retrieve the phone number from the NUMBER column
                    int column = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);
                    String number = cursor.getString(column);
                    System.out.println("newNum value" + number);
                    String newNum = number.replaceAll("-", "").trim();

                    newNum=newNum.replace("+91", "");
                    /*System.out.println("newNum value" + newNum);
                    String tempNumber = newNum.substring(number.length()-10, number.length());
                    System.out.println("tempNumber value" + tempNumber);*/
                    mob_no.setText(newNum);
                    }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {       
        new AlertDialog.Builder(getParent()).setTitle("Sign out").setMessage("Do you want to sign out?")
        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dialog.dismiss();
                finish();
            }
        }).setNegativeButton("No", null).create().show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you put a breakpoint in onActivityResult() method?

Comment: @user3432982 on the line super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); ?

Comment: Also are the onActivityResult() and contact.setOnCLickListener() in the same class?

Comment: yes, onActivityResult() and contacti.setOnClickListener() are in the same class. contact.setOnClickListener() is in the onCreate() method and onActivityResult() method is outside of onCreate() method. but both are same class.

Comment: problem is created when we use this code in 2 tabhost, this code is written in first tab of second tabhost. First tabhost are used in upper, and second tabhost is used in below side of each tab of first tabhost.

Comment: @user3432982 well i might be able to help you only if i get your whole code. Do you use GitHub or anything like that??

Comment: @user3432982 then can you upload your project there and give the link here?

Answer (score -1):

The solution is simple, after some time and testing.

It worked by doing the following.

// The main class containing the MainActivity.java Tabs

1. that extends from TabActivity

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends TabActivity{
   ```
2. this sets the TabHost

   ```
   TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
   localActivityManager = getLocalActivityManager();
   tabHost.setup(localActivityManager);

   //The tabs are added
   tabHost.addTab(fotoIntent)
   ```

Only this is needed for the trigger onResume onActivityResult and works in the Internal Tabs.

Comment: Please try to answer in English so that it will benefit a larger audience.